# How to prevent my PSTricks codes from interfering the imported EPS files?

Tags: pstricks, eps, dvips

My main input file not only contains PSTricks codes but also imports EPS images produced by `epstool` from standalone PSTricks input files compiled with `dvips input.dvi -E -o output.eps`.

I am worried whether the following warning that I got from [epstool](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/ghostscript/ghostgum) will endanger me.

> The PostScript code must avoid using
>   PostScript operators that would
>   interfere with the embedding. These
>   include operators with global effects
>   such as changing the page size and
>   changing the half tone screen.

How to make sure I am safe?

Comment: I never saw such stetement. Provide an example dvi _and_ eps file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`epstool --test-eps file.eps` will attempt to test for some PostScript constructions that are forbidden or risky to use in EPS. I have never used this so I don't know how accurate it is.